# how to convert the parsed data contains text and image url to text view and image view using Glide?

Tags: android, json, user-interface, android-imageview, android-glide

i have tried glide ...but unable to handel it..."https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/" in this tutorial they used a image class. is it necessary or it can be solved by Glide or picaso?  i am new to android please help.
My main activity

```
String name = persons.getString("name");
                    String skills = persons.getString("skills");
                    String image = persons.getString("image");
                // tmp hash map for single person
                HashMap<String, String> person = new HashMap<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                person.put("name", name);
                person.put("skills", skills);

            /*    Glide.with(getApplicationContext ())
                        .load(image)
                        .into();*/
                // adding person toperson list
                personList.add(person);
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter (
                        MainActivity.this, personList,
                        R.layout.persons_list, new String[]{"name", "skills"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                        R.id.skills});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes Glide or Picasso is easy way of handling images in listviews and recyclerviews. You need to have a custom adapter as your each person has a image to load.

Create a model class like following;

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private String skills;
private String image;

// getters and setters
}
```

then you need a custom adapter class like following;

```
public class PersonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Person> mData;

public PersonAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Person> data) {
    super(context, 0, data);

    mContext = context;
    mData = data;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPerson);
        holder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.skills = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSkills);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    Person person = getItem(position);

    holder.name.setText(person.getName());
    holder.skills.setText(person.getSkills());
    // set image with picasso
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(person.getImage()).into(holder.image);

    return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView name;
    TextView skills;
}
}
```

Its always good to use a ViewHolder to hold your data as it will make it easy for memory handling

Then in the activity create a instance of adapter and attach it to your listview

```
PersonAdapter adapter = new PersonAdapter(MainActivity.this, persons);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i have used Picasso, you can use Glide as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a pojo class for person then you can 
use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) for data parsing like this:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 Persons persons = gson.fromJson(productList, Persons.class);
```

Then you can use glide like this:

```
requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions
            .placeholder(placeholder)
            .error(error)
            .dontTransform()
            .dontAnimate();
    Glide.with(mContext).load(url).apply(requestOptions).into(imageView);
```